# Why does PineBerry advertise PCIE Gen3 NVME, and Raspberry PI 5 claims Gen2?

Tags: pi-5

According to [Pineberry's listing for HatDrive! Top (NVMe 2230, 2242 GEN 3) for Raspberry Pi 5](https://pineberrypi.com/products/hat-top-2230-2240-for-rpi5)

The title says "Gen 3", and the text says,

> PCIe Interface Support: Offers support for PCIe x1 interface in both Gen2 and **Gen3** standards.

But the listing for [Raspberry Pi 5](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-5/) says,

> **PCIe 2.0** x1 interface for fast peripherals (requires separate M.2 HAT or other adapter)

How do I make sense of these claims for PCIe 2.0 and PCIe 3.0?  If the Raspberry Pi 5 has no PCIe 3.0 support, I can buy the cheapest NVME drive (since PCIe 2.0 is old at this point). Otherwise I may want to sport a more modern drive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pi 5 does support PCIe3 but it’s not official (yet)

To enable experimental and not-officially-supported PCIe 3 mode, add the follow line to the [all] section at the end of your Raspberry Pi `/boot/config.txt` file like this:

```
[all]
dtparam=pciex1_gen=3
```